# ExtJs LoadMask disapper on screen resize

Tags: css, extjs, extjs5

Hello Friends,

We are using ExtJs 5.1 for UI developement and to have custom font color on [Ext.grid.Panel](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel) LoadMask I have override the css clas 
`x-mask-msg-text` and apply it to LoadMask, code as below.
 This works fine, but when I re-size browser window or open console window using *F12* LoadMask disappears before loading grid panel. Please advice.

```
     .custom-mask .x-mask-msg-text{

        background-color: transparent !important;
        color: #e6e6ff !important;
        font-weight:bold !important;
     }


        new Ext.LoadMask({
            cls: 'custom-mask',
            msg: "Loading...",
            target: Ext.getBody()
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a well known issue for Sencha's Ext JS. But there are some workarounds, please check out the following forum thread:

https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?297130&p=1085032&viewfull=1#post1085032